# Where do we download Betaflight Configurator and Blackbox Explorer?

Tags: betaflight, software

I have picked up an older quad to get some experience in FPV flying.  I'm not sure of the make or model of the quad - it doesn't seem to have a label.  It does come with some printed instructions for setup and use, but these seem to be out-of-date.

The instructions say that I need *Betaflight Configurator* and *Blackbox Explorer* and that these should be downloaded from the Chrome Web Store.  However, those apps don't appear to be available from the Chrome Web Store.

After a few Google searches, I found that they were removed following Google's announcement that they were going to be withdrawing support for all Chrome Apps. I also found an announcement that Betaflight would be developing standalone apps to replace the ones that were going to be removed from the Chrome Web Store.  Unfortunately, those announcements don't say where the new standalone apps will be available from.

Now, I have searched, and I've found several sites that offer apps called '*Betaflight Configurator*' and '*Blackbox Explorer*', however, none seem to be official download sites (and several of them trigger safety warnings when I click on the links).  Besides which, everyone knows that we shouldn't be downloading software these days unless it is from a trusted source.

---

So my question is simple.

**Where is the official download site for '*Betaflight Configurator*' and '*Blackbox Explorer*'?**

Comment: After downloading betaflight make sure you also install all the drivers recommended on the beta flight opening page in the left hand side, specially the STM drivers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Betaflight software is available from [the Betaflight GitHub pages](https://github.com/betaflight). These give the option of downloading pre-compiled binaries or the source code if you prefer to compile yourself.

- [Betaflight Configurator](https://github.com/betaflight/betaflight-configurator/releases)
- [Blackbox log viewer](https://github.com/betaflight/blackbox-log-viewer/releases)

Answer (score 1):

The absolute latest versions are available from the Betaflight Github:

[Betaflight Configurator nightlies](https://github.com/betaflight/betaflight-configurator-nightlies)

[Betaflight Blackbox Explorer nightlies](https://github.com/betaflight/blackbox-log-viewer-nightlies)